# put ImageView src to HashMap<String, String>

Tags: android

Please take a look my code first:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//... 
ImageView temp = new ImageView(MyApp.this);
temp.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
//...
HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(i);
map.put("pic", temp.toString()); //"pic" will map to a ImageView
```

**Here is my questione:**

I know,

```
map.put("pic", temp.toString());
```

is wrong.

But what is the correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract there? You won't be able to extract the resource reference only the `Drawable`.

Comment: So, I cant set ImageView in this way?

Comment: I want to set the ImageView from server and want it do in the task. So, I need to know how to change the ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to include image ids in hash map is to use HashMap where object corresponds to the image ids (int). Do try this I have worked on it myself.

Comment: what if i want to show the id of an image i download with picasso using url image? How do i add it to the hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the resource reference of an `ImageView`. You can only get the `Drawable` by calling `getDrawable()` on that `ImageView`.

It won't help you to get the string representation of that `Drawable`.

Comment: Is there a way can I change the ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

First get the drawable id of your icon or image with this.

```
 int idImage = getResources().getIdentifier("R.drawable.icon", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

use `getActivity()` before call `getPackageName()` if you are using fragments.

then pass the `idImage` to `String` and put that in your HashMap

```
 String idImageString = String.valueOf(idImage);

 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

 map.put("imageList", idImageString);
 productsList.add(map);
```

Comment: what if i want to show the id of an image i download with picasso using url image? How do i add it to the hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display image from drawable folder into hashmap you can do it very easily...You can display that also display them into image view or whatever..

```
HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
file_maps.put("Picture1",R.drawable.pic1);
file_maps.put("Picture2",R.drawable.pic2);
for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
        // initialize a SliderLayout
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

        //add your extra information
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

       mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
```

The main thing is < string, integer>